# Where do I go to pay for the museum renovation?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Since Redd finally visited my town, I can now pay to have a second floor built in the museum.  The problem is, I don't know *where* to pay for it.  I've spoken to Isabelle and started the public works project, but I've been all over the museum and can't find where to donate funds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gyroid responsible for collecting funds for the museum renovation is located in the **train station**, nowhere near the museum.

Comment: This is the case for all renovations on main street, and Isabelle tells you when you start the project, each time.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig After completing various non-main street projects, it's pretty easy to assume you know how the system works and skim through the system.  Then when you get to one of the main street projects, you have no idea what to do.

Comment: If you're ignoring Isabelle you're a monster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to go to the train station to pay for the museum Renovation. You will find Lloid  on your left hand side. Hope; this was helpful.